# Замена подстроки в строке с++

Tags: c++

Есть в котором встречаются `<i>` и `</i>`. Заменить каждое вхождение `<i>` на `<курсив>`, а каждое вхождение `</i>` на `<конец курсив>`. Помогите такое реализовать.

Comment: Что-то мне нечего не понятно...Вам нужно заменить все `<i> и </i>` на что именно???Курсив, всмысле html тег соответствующий? Дак курсив и есть тег `<i>` или Вам именно на слово в теге `<курсив>`?

Answer (score 5):

Вариант решения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string StringReplacer(const std::string& inputStr, const std::string& src, const std::string& dst)
{
    std::string result(inputStr);

    size_t pos = result.find(src);
    while(pos != std::string::npos) {
        result.replace(pos, src.size(), dst);
        pos = result.find(src, pos);
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str = "<i>asd</i><i>qwe</i>";
    std::string res = StringReplacer(str, "<i>", "<italic>");
    std::string res2 = StringReplacer(res, "</i>", "<end italic>");
    std::cout << "Result string: " << res2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ломается при `StringReplacer("hex", "x", "hex")` – уходит в бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Короткий вариант для С++03 (в более новый версиях нужно заменить только пространство имён для `regex` c `std::tr1` на `std`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::string ReplaceAll(const std::string& inputStr, const std::string& src, const std::string& dst)
{
    std::tr1::regex rx(src.c_str());
    return std::tr1::regex_replace(inputStr, rx, dst);  
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str = "<i>asd</i><i>qwe</i>";
    std::string res = ReplaceAll(str, "<i>", "<italic>");
    std::string res2 = ReplaceAll(res, "</i>", "<end italic>");
    std::cout << "Result string: " << res2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Функция `main` позаимствована у [Malov Vladimir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218921/malov-vladimir)