# Помогите, нужно заменить один символ строки на несколько

Tags: c++

Помогите, нужно заменить один символ строки на несколько но я знаю как заменить один на другой а на несколько не знаю.
Надо '.' заменить на '...'
Вот пример замени одного на другой

```
int Input(char a[1000]);              
int Manipulation(char a[1000], int i);  
int Output(char a[1000]);               
char a[1000];    
int i;           

void main(){
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
Input(a);                  
Manipulation(a,i);          
Output(a);                 
getch();
}



int Input(char a[1000]){
cout<<"\t\tВведiть стрiчку \n";
gets(a);
}

int Manipulation(char a[1000], int i){
i = 0;
while (*(a+i)!= '\0' )
{
if ( *(a+i)== ',' )
  *(a+i)='.';
i++;
} 
}

int Output(char a[1000]) {
clrscr();
puts ("\n\t\tПеретворена стрiчка:\n");
puts(a);
}
```

Comment: вам принципиально использование char*? на строках все значительно проще

Comment: нет char не принципиально

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена подстроки в строке с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568827/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight , ну допустим когда то кто то задавал похожий вопрос. И что с этого: всем бояться задавать вопрос, пока тшательно не  пересмотрят все ранее заданные похожие вопросы?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, бояться? Зачем? Система никак не наказывает авторов дубликатов именно из-за того, что невозможно заранее всё отследить.

Answer (score 0):

Часто лучше написать более обобщенный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
void replace_n (char* m,  const size_t N, const char c = ',', const char new_char = '.')
  {   
      char* p = std::find(m, m + strlen(m), c);
      if (!*p) return; // если нет указанного символа, ничего не делать
      std::fill_n(p, N, new_char);          
  }    
int main()
{    
    char arr[50];
    std::cin.getline(arr, 50);
    // заменить первую запятую и последующие 2 символа символом '.'
    replace_n(arr, 3);
    std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    // заменить первую точку и последующие 4 символа символом  '0'
    replace_n(arr, 5, '.', '0');
    std::cout << arr;
    // и т.д и т.п.
    return 0;
}
```

хотя тут еще не обработаны случаи выхода за пределы массива

Comment: Обработать  выход за пределы массива (при замене, например 
 3-х  символов, если ваш символ находится перед завершающим символом) оставлю вам, чтобы  был и ваш вклад в код

Comment: Нет ви не поняли мне нужно подвинуть букви после запятой а не заменить