# Замена слов в строке c++

Tags: c++, строки

Необходимо ввести строку и вывести эту строку на экран, заменив все сочетания символов "нет" на "да"\
Сделал код, но при компиляции выходит ошибка(debug error). Программа работает только когда я прописываю текст в коде.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    using namespace std;
    string s;
    cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    s.replace(s.find("нет"), 3, "да"); //поиск и замена строки
    cout << s;
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, этим `cin >> s;` вы вводите только **одно слово**. О работе с результатом `find` без проверки, что она вернула - я вообще молчу... Все равно что ехать на машине, не проверяя тормоза, или трескать какую-то еду, не глядя на срок годности. Примерно так...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568827/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81

Comment: Можно в одну строчку: `std::regex_replace(s, std::regex(R"нет"), "да");` Такое решение, правда, может быть несколько медленнее, чем решение из комментария выше в связи с реализацией регулярок в С++, но это требует замеров по-хорошему.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, у вас будет работать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string s;
    cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    int val = s.find("да");
    if(val == -1){
        cout << "Не найдено" << endl;
    }else{
        s.replace(s.find("да"), 3, "да");
    }
        cout << s;
        cout << "\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```